# which is more efficient - map or 3 arrays?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was wondering which solution is more efficient. I have an array of objects, let's say, cars. Each of these cars have a status: NEW, PURCHASED and DAMAGED. I need to display 3 tabs: tab with new cars, with purchased cars and with damaged cars. Unfortunately the backend doesn't give already filtered response, I have to filter it manually on the frontend. So my initial solution was something like that:

```
const newCars = useMemo(() => {
    const arr = cars
        .filter((car) => car.status === 'new')
        .map((it) => ({
            id: it.id,       
        }));
    return arr;
}, [cars]);
```

then I just use newCars array, and map it to display some JSX content:

```
newCars.map((item, index) => (
    <CarItem
    key={item.id}                                           
    />
```

Filtering the cars array is done 3 times. I thought - would Map be more efficient? Let's say something like this:

```
const carsMap = useMemo(() => {
    const result = new Map<string, []>();

    const statuses = ["new", "purchased", "damaged"];

    for (let i = 0; i < statuses.length; i++) {
        const arr = cars
            .filter((car) => car.status === statuses[i])
            .map((it) => ({
                id: it.id,
                //...mapping props here
            }));

        result.set(statuses[i], arr);
    }

    return result;
}, [cars]);
```

and then I access for example new cars by using:

```
carsMap.get("new").map((item, index) => (
    <CarItem
    key={index}/>
   ))
```

Which solution is better (in terms of clean code and performance)?

Both solutions returns the same output, but I dont know which is better.

Comment: [Race your horses](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/).  It's entirely possible, even likely, that the performance difference between the two is negligble enough for the use case that whichever code is simpler and easier to understand/support would be the way to go.  Considerations include how large these arrays are, how often this re-rendering occurs, how well the memoization already helps, etc.

Answer (score 3):

If you care about performance I would suggest using [`Array#reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

Currently, even in your second approach with a `Map` you are still iterating 3 times, because for every status you are running `.filter()` on the original array, so essentially you are iterating the same amount of times in your both solutions.

Using `.reduce()` will iterate only one time. Here's how you can do it:

```
const carsMap = useMemo(() => {
    return cars.reduce((res, curr) => {
      if (res.has(curr.status)) {              // if the status already exists in the result map...
        const statuses = res.get(curr.status); // grab the reference to the array and...
        statuses.push(curr);                   // push the new car.
      } else {
        res.set(curr.status, [curr]);          // else, set a new status array
      }
      
      return res;
    }, new Map<string, []>());
}, [cars]);
```

and then you can access it like this (same as your second approach):

```
carsMap.get("new").map((item, index) => (
    <CarItem
    key={index}/>
   ))
```

Answer (score 0):

The Map approach!

You only perform the filtering and mapping of the original cars array once. After that, you have direct access to pre-filtered arrays for each status without needing to re-filter the main array multiple times. This can be more efficient compared to filtering the cars array separately for each tab.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of converting a flat list of items into a grouped-by-status object. I used Lodash's `groupBy` function to simplify the code below.

Pay attention to each effect and memo hook. It monitors the changes to the data as it it converted from a list, to an object, and finally an array of `<Tab>` components.

This object can then be converted to a list of tab objects identified by a name. Each tab can then hold a child that represents a car list component.

The entire flow can be found below:

```js
const { useCallback, useEffect, useMemo, useState } = React;
const { groupBy } = _;

const fetchCars = () => Promise.resolve([
  { "id":  1, "make": "Dodge",       "model": "Viper",         "year": 1991, "status": "purchased" },
  { "id":  2, "make": "Chevrolet",   "model": "Corvette",      "year": 1953, "status": "purchased" },
  { "id":  3, "make": "Lamborghini", "model": "Countach",      "year": 1974, "status": "purchased" },
  { "id":  4, "make": "Porsche",     "model": "911",           "year": 1964, "status": "purchased" },
  { "id":  5, "make": "Ferrari",     "model": "Daytona",       "year": 1968, "status": "new"       },
  { "id":  6, "make": "Nissan",      "model": "Z-Car",         "year": 1969, "status": "new"       },
  { "id":  7, "make": "Toyota",      "model": "Supra Mark IV", "year": 1994, "status": "new"       },
  { "id":  8, "make": "Honda",       "model": "NSX",           "year": 1990, "status": "damaged"   },
  { "id":  9, "make": "Mazda",       "model": "MX-5 Miata",    "year": 1989, "status": "damaged"   },
  { "id": 10, "make": "MG",          "model": "MGB",           "year": 1962, "status": "damaged"   },
]);

const tabOrder = ["new", "purchased", "damaged"];

const Tab = ({ active, name, onClick }) => {
  return (
    <div className="Tab" data-active={active} data-name={name} onClick={onClick}>
      {name}
    </div>
  );
};

const TabBar = ({ activeName, onClick, tabData }) => {
  return (
    <div className="TabBar">
      {tabData.map(({ name, data }) => (
        <Tab key={name} active={name === activeName} name={name} onClick={onClick} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

const TabView = ({ activeTab, children, onClick, tabData }) => {
  const activeName = activeTab || tabData[0].name;
  const activeIndex = tabData.findIndex(t => t.name === activeName);
  return (
    <div className="TabView">
      <TabBar activeName={activeName} onClick={onClick} tabData={tabData} />
      <div className="TabContent">
        {children[activeIndex]}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

const CarInfo = ({ id, make, model, year }) => {
  return (
    <div className="CarInfo" data-id={id}>
      {year} {make} {model}
    </div>
  );
};

const CarList = ({ cars }) => {
  return (
    <div className="CarList">
      <ul>
        {cars.map(({ id, make, model, year }) => (
          <li key={id}>
            <CarInfo id={id} make={make} model={model} year={year} />
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

const App = ({ title }) => {
  const [carsByStatusMap, setCarsByStatusMap] = useState(null);
  const [activeTab, setActiveTab] = useState(null);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchCars().then(cars => setCarsByStatusMap(groupBy(cars, 'status')))
  }, []);
  
  const tabClick = useCallback((e) => {
    setActiveTab(e.target.dataset.name);
  }, []);
  
  const tabData = useMemo(() => tabOrder.map(key => ({
    name: key,
    data: carsByStatusMap ? (carsByStatusMap[key] || []) : []
  })), [carsByStatusMap]);
  
  const tabs = useMemo(() => tabData.map(({ name, data }) => (
    <CarList key={name} cars={data} />
  )), [tabData]);
    
  return (
    <div>
      <TabView activeTab={activeTab} onClick={tabClick} tabData={tabData}>
        {tabs}
      </TabView>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM
  .createRoot(document.getElementById("root"))
  .render(<App />);
```

```css
*, *::before, *::after { box-sizing: border-box; }

* { color: #FFF; }

html, body, #root { width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; }

#root {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: #222;
}

.TabView {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: thin solid #333;
  width: 80vw;
  height: 80vh;
  background: #444;
}

.TabBar {
  display: flex;
  background: #111;
}

.Tab {
  display: flex;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  background: #222;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

.Tab[data-active="true"] {
  background: #444;
}

.Tab:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #555;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

**Note:** Since the Babel version here is older, the following:

```js
data: carsByStatusMap ? (carsByStatusMap[key] || []) : []
```

May be simplified to:

```js
data: carsByStatusMap?.[key] ?? []
```